# Check if a variable was statically or dynamically allocated or not?

Tags: c, malloc, free

I'm implementing my own malloc and free functions. How can I have an error check that passes in a static variable over a dynamically allocated variable?
Let's say I have:

```
char foo[10];
void *bar = malloc(5); 

void free(void *p)
```

Is there a way to tell the user that this is an error?

```
free(foo)
```

Comment: If you are implementing your own malloc you should be able to keep a list of everything that was allocated, should you choose to do so.  Anything not on that list should be illegal to free.

Comment: Why not study an existing implementation? http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html is a good starting point. Once you've done that, you'll be able to come up with additional ideas (for example, add a magic signature to the chunk header, and check that signature in `free()`).

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is to maintain a table of allocated pointers within your memory management functions.

Don't forget to remove entries when releasing memory.

Answer (score 0):

This might sounds crazy ,

You need to maintain your allocated pointers from your custom malloc() function in a list/structure. Then when using your custom free() function check whether variable exists inside your maintained list/structure.